# Is String value the same as Integer value

Tags: java, string, integer

I am using the following commands to convert String to Integer:

```
String input = "58";
int result = Integer.parseInt(input);           
System.out.println(result);
```

Is String "58" the same as Integer 58?

Comment: What do you mean with "the same" ?

Comment: The string is a string, and the integer is an integer. They're not the same. Whether that affects the code in your other class depends on what that code is doing.

Comment: I mean is 58 in String the same 58 in Integer

Comment: Both, `int` and `String` may represent the same value, but they are not the same primitive or object.

Comment: No, String "58" is not the same as Integer 58. But if you compere result variable from your code to 58 it will return true.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean this codes always gives me the same value, so can I use it in my second class, when I need Integer 58, this code will convert String 58 to Integer 58.

Comment: It depends what you're other class is doing.

Comment: If you trie to make an arithemtic operation using string "58" it won't work. exemple: "58" + 5 will result in "585" and not 63 like a normal math adition if you use int.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to understand, this is answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "58"

int yourInt = 58

input == yourInt => false
```

but

```
String input = "58"

int result = Integer.parseInt(input)

int yourInt = 58

input == result => true
```

I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, this is answered my question,,

Answer (score 0):

The `58` as `String` is not same as `58` as `int`.
Both have different values. As both has different datatypes.
`Integer.parseInt()` will try to convert `String` datatype into compatible `int` datatype.